# Atlas for sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, spheres

I was asked to find 3 different atlas for the surface **sphere of rad 1 ($S^2$)**. 
(As an Atlas is a collection of local parametrizations of surface, whose Union gives the whole surface, or they combine covers the whole surface.)

I have managed to find 2 atlas for sphere of radius 1... That are given below...

First Atlas is $\{ f_i : i = 1,2, ... 6\}$ and
$U_1= \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 ; x^2+y^2<1 \}$
With
$ f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4,f_5,f_6 : U_1 \to S^2 $
S.t
$f_{1,2} (x,y) = (x,y, \pm \sqrt {1-x^2-y^2} )$
$f_{3,4} (x,y) = (x, \pm \sqrt {1-x^2-y^2} , y)$
$f_{5,6} (x,y) = (\pm \sqrt {1-x^2-y^2} , x, y)$

And the second atlas is $\{f_7,f_8\}$
Where
$f_7,f_8 : U_2 \to S^2$ with 
$U_2 = \{ (x,y) ; 0<x<π , 0<y<2π\}$ and
$f_7(x,y) = (\sin x \cos y , \sin x \sin y , \cos x )$
$f_8(x,y) = (-\sin x \cos y , \cos x , - \sin x \sin y)$

Now I m trying to find the 3rd one...
If any one have any mapping in mind, which maps an open set in $\Bbb R^2$ to the sphere or some part of that sphere of rad 1, please share...

Comment: Take their union?

Comment: Stereographic projection?

Comment: @LeeMosher sir.. i need another mapping like these 2, on which i made some little changes to make a complete cover for unit sphere (as i done before shown above)....

Comment: @TedShifrin yes... I tried but i was unable to understand that... 

Comment: Their union is a 3rd different atlas from either of the two. So if you want to impose stricter conditions on the 3rd atlas that you seek, you should explain this better in your question.

Comment: @LeeMosher actually an atlas is a collection of local parametrizations, and a local parametrization is a $C^infin$ mapping f from and open set U in $R^2$ to the surface which satisfies 3 conditions,. (f(U) is open in surface) (f is homeomorphism with its image) (df is injective), so their union might not satisfy all this....

Comment: The conditions you wrote are a property satisfied by each individual element of the atlas. If each individual element of two atlases satisfy that property, so does each individual element of their union.

Comment: @LeeMosher will u please wrote down mathematically?

Answer (score 1):

For a third atlas, you can just take the union of the two atlases you have considered already, namely:
$$\{f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4,f_5,f_6\} \cup \{f_7,f_8\} = \{f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4,f_5,f_6,f_7,f_8\}
$$